# Firefox does not offer client certificate: SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT

Tags: firefox, ssl, certificate

A CA certificate expired and was regenerated with the same private key, with
the existing client certificates working in Chrome, but failing within Firefox:

> An error occurred during a connection to example.com:
>  SSL peer was unable to negotiate an acceptable set  of security parameters:
>
> ```
> Error code: SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT
> ```

Firefox does not prompt for the client certificate and does not send it - suspecting that something does not match the client certificate selection process.

How could this be debugged on Firefox side? 
 How does Firefox decide when to ask for / offer the client certificate?

Please note that [web]server certificate is working properly and is out of scope here.

**What has been verified:**

- Fails both on Firefox 78 on Mac and Firefox 77 on Linux; the same client certificate that worked with the previous CA certificate is present in both Firefox instances.
- On Mac, where the same client certificate works in Chrome and thus is present in Keychain, enabling `security.osclientcerts.autoload` in Firefox does not help.
- "Acceptable client certificate CA names" match between the old and new CA certificate.
- "Client Certificate Types" seems to be acceptable: 
   New certificate: RSA sign, DSA sign, ECDSA sign 
   Old certificate: RSA fixed DH, DSS fixed DH, RSA sign, DSA sign
- Presence of v3 extensions in the CA certificate does not matter (including the setting of `CA:TRUE`).
- CRL is used but has not expired, and client certificate is not revoked.
- The serial number on the old and new CA certificate are different and seems to be large random numbers.
- Client certificate does not seem to contain any (expired) chain certificates.
- Regenerating the CA certificate to have validity period start before the client certificate does not help.
- Regenerating CA certificate to be SHA1 does not help (the old CA certificate was SHA1).

**Certificates**

CA certificate (with X509v3 extensions; their presence / lack of it makes no difference):

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            cb:b5:11:9e:17:0f:aa:30
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: <string>
        Validity
            Not Before: Jul 16 12:04:27 2020 GMT
            Not After : Apr 15 12:04:27 2030 GMT
        Subject: <string>
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:c1:16:6b:74:7e:b7:d0:da:8b:7f:55:bf:ee:c3:
                    c1:c3:ff:48:8a:b2:2d:a9:48:17:f1:aa:8b:36:34:
                    21:b2:d8:22:09:7c:ba:7c:61:83:a9:0e:40:69:4c:
                    b9:ed:25:dc:e6:f0:f8:45:b6:a6:14:2f:7a:2b:bc:
                    6d:9d:d3:d7:f5:4a:bd:dc:38:ed:88:f7:47:73:0a:
                    41:6f:15:a0:83:34:55:7b:4c:39:1d:8e:de:60:1f:
                    81:df:42:f5:b5:b9:0d:f5:90:9a:c4:80:ef:a7:1c:
                    38:93:c0:83:43:9b:5b:ef:cf:30:1a:70:29:26:e5:
                    e2:35:0e:81:24:e7:97:75:d1:ae:f7:a4:bc:e7:28:
                    20:52:87:58:87:41:2f:4b:ca:cd:2d:af:08:8b:bf:
                    1f:a5:a3:e1:f3:d0:81:f1:9c:f6:36:a2:d4:8f:2e:
                    19:67:72:2d:41:2c:43:d9:4f:b5:6b:2d:60:e0:77:
                    39:2e:53:20:7d:49:fa:c0:43:f2:03:cc:17:71:93:
                    cb:42:4e:42:41:23:2e:86:7c:b1:64:dc:a3:e4:7c:
                    60:37:43:56:ed:25:c5:97:ab:4d:90:98:c9:34:48:
                    b2:bc:34:f9:fb:89:cb:20:62:25:91:cf:8f:dd:bd:
                    40:d6:03:bf:b5:fc:cd:f8:c9:db:df:25:bb:f7:17:
                    31:8d
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                A8:C5:5A:EC:01:FD:DE:76:54:E1:94:97:EC:35:B6:C4:23:8A:73:FC
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:A8:C5:5A:EC:01:FD:DE:76:54:E1:94:97:EC:35:B6:C4:23:8A:73:FC
                DirName:<string>
                serial:CB:B5:11:9E:17:0F:AA:30

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         33:90:66:8c:e4:99:c4:4e:1c:b7:5c:7d:b7:16:67:f1:b4:bc:
         d6:b2:ce:36:c3:4f:77:db:e3:22:89:5c:63:cb:a4:0b:62:b4:
         c5:72:d8:37:02:c7:1b:83:0b:03:ad:c6:51:20:e1:fd:c8:28:
         72:ea:62:da:be:e7:0b:68:e7:f2:7d:24:b6:59:2f:ab:4c:76:
         ba:42:38:fe:fb:e4:a1:91:ab:0f:9b:08:3f:d2:98:3b:c2:75:
         78:97:cf:97:34:8f:c1:3f:b9:bd:a4:53:6d:ea:bc:03:33:86:
         a3:46:8f:b8:6e:09:be:67:43:d8:c4:17:85:3a:9e:e9:c0:86:
         fc:d4:25:51:e0:36:d2:fc:ca:84:43:68:a8:75:f5:b8:a3:87:
         71:8d:b4:e9:78:69:b3:4d:52:10:ed:05:df:a0:b3:0d:34:f9:
         a0:99:99:29:12:74:d6:74:55:05:1b:7e:6c:81:48:ba:a2:05:
         9e:f3:33:2b:6f:14:25:8a:a9:c6:ff:7d:28:01:03:32:3e:46:
         68:b1:88:f2:04:b0:bd:83:a0:97:ca:12:84:03:49:9c:f6:63:
         14:24:45:ab:dd:73:97:33:a0:fd:0e:94:95:b1:cb:95:cc:c3:
         6c:82:fc:05:70:3d:9b:0e:ea:05:6e:e2:36:c1:2f:b3:87:b6:
         ca:58:59:b1
```

Client certificate:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 302 (0x12e)
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: <string>
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 26 08:11:41 2020 GMT
            Not After : Mar 26 08:11:41 2022 GMT
        Subject: <string>
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:b1:07:3c:54:4f:4c:77:66:75:21:c5:9d:1f:b0:
                    da:92:ee:5f:4f:a9:79:a3:56:a9:fd:ec:0f:ff:c9:
                    23:de:3f:6a:f4:e3:5b:f5:d0:ef:cf:ae:1d:a8:80:
                    21:76:39:1e:e6:90:1a:da:dd:07:21:68:98:73:29:
                    ea:f2:40:fe:9f:a3:b9:af:89:20:7d:0f:22:cb:cc:
                    50:de:30:af:66:00:52:93:2c:f1:a0:f5:7d:46:6e:
                    c9:63:d9:c4:24:0a:db:9c:8c:66:52:04:f1:da:f8:
                    8b:71:27:46:60:98:94:49:b0:b2:05:e5:5d:7c:05:
                    8d:e0:51:35:eb:38:ae:d3:d7:dc:a5:21:72:d4:b9:
                    9a:be:29:3f:04:bd:11:c3:43:b7:d8:56:2b:4b:60:
                    08:9e:a9:77:55:a4:e6:d1:b8:b6:2b:57:ff:89:bc:
                    0a:87:b2:43:71:0c:aa:65:28:20:09:68:63:0b:d8:
                    2e:de:05:bf:40:95:a7:24:b4:2e:a0:c4:d8:37:66:
                    3e:28:d1:7b:4e:77:4f:23:7e:e7:44:85:3d:70:fc:
                    eb:34:06:2a:9d:40:c9:30:0f:a6:df:0a:51:1e:54:
                    31:22:a9:d7:8b:7c:84:88:ef:77:ca:34:00:27:52:
                    ef:34:d0:a5:a2:41:79:bd:45:0d:85:70:00:01:2c:
                    6a:f7
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Client Authentication
            Netscape Cert Type: 
                SSL Client
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         5c:c1:da:4a:ba:37:21:54:24:21:f5:6f:83:b4:74:78:17:cb:
         d3:f8:63:a3:07:9c:34:7c:51:e5:97:4d:70:41:fa:91:1a:ce:
         6f:87:32:24:81:65:00:3b:9a:c1:f6:32:82:9a:cc:6d:68:3e:
         03:b7:3a:3d:3c:81:15:89:f8:12:27:b3:cd:d3:e5:7a:bd:e9:
         49:f4:c1:19:58:39:dc:13:58:2c:8b:1b:a7:c6:ae:28:ad:4c:
         9e:76:77:ff:fa:36:04:94:fb:bd:87:fe:f0:a5:2e:85:d8:29:
         50:b6:c5:43:9b:f4:bd:5a:35:40:1f:23:59:e2:04:84:f2:b9:
         91:ef:20:fe:99:28:e4:df:71:96:4a:ab:35:5c:57:c2:46:80:
         20:7c:be:49:37:18:d1:0f:07:47:54:1c:e3:33:78:e0:c1:61:
         93:bf:95:fd:f4:bd:27:a4:f1:6b:ba:62:8c:79:a0:57:ee:d3:
         bd:08:73:b1:37:41:10:68:38:7a:91:c5:3a:64:1b:54:66:b4:
         19:cc:16:16:5d:94:7a:e2:f7:2b:79:bd:2a:ab:01:67:32:e9:
         4a:2b:fb:da:df:5b:65:36:1a:8b:1d:a9:3c:2a:3f:bd:02:f0:
         eb:9b:e2:3b:46:0d:44:f8:ac:77:ac:6f:60:df:a5:27:00:4c:
         8c:9f:a0:2c
```

Comment: Do you have on firefox's trusted certificates the expired CA? Have you tried to load the new CA into Firefox?

Comment: Firefox did not trust the expired CA certificate (it is not used for the sever certificate, only for the client certificate). To be on the safe side, I did try to trust the CA certificate, no change.

Comment: Do you have OCSP or CRL enabled? Could be that Firefox is checking whether the client cert is revoked and getting an expired CRL or OCSP response. Also Firefox is REALLY picky with certificates and would refuse to work if it sees a duplicate serial for the same CA. I don't think that should be a problem with the CA itself, but make sure that on renewal you change the serial.

Comment: Are you really using user certs for authentication to a web server? I didn't know anyone went to that kind of trouble.

Comment: @NuttyX, CRL is enabled, has not expired, client certificate is not revoked (and has not expired). Serial on the CA certificate was not checked, will look into that.

Comment: @Spiff, yes, client certificates are used for authentication to a webserver.

Comment: @NuttyX, checking serial number on the old and new CA certificate, they are different (and seem to be large random numbers). I've also updated the "What has been verified" section with additional info.

Comment: Not really sure of this applies to ffox: in some cases, when you import a P12 you could either have the final cert alone or the cert alongside the chain that signs it. If you check the cert on the ffox cert page, it could show the previous CA as expired (so the cert itself is unusable) so try to export it, delete (or replace) the CA in the chain and import it again.

Comment: Thanks, the client certificate does not seem to contain any chain certificates.

Comment: @Richlv If allowing the CA to auto-manage serials by not manually setting the starting serial in `serial` _(in hex)_, it will apply a random large number for the serial when signing the cert. It wasn't clear from your bullet, but `CA:TRUE` should only be set on a CA or ICA, and _**never**_ on any other cert. Please paste the output of the following into a code box for all certs in the trust chain _(CA, ICA [if applicable], and certificate)_: `openssl x509 -inform pem -in name.crt.pem -noout -text`

Comment: Client certs user `serial`, CA certs use random ones, I believe. CA:TRUE was only set for the CA cert, but made no difference. I've added CA and client certs in the post (with some detail censored).

Comment: Did you double-click on the client cert in the list (on the ffox interface) to see all details of the certificate? If it was loaded with a CA (I've just tried it locally) it would show a button with the name of the CA to the side of the name of the cert, and only the name of the cert if no CA was loaded.

Comment: @JW0914, that's the client certificate, containing the encipherment and client authentication usage - that's the same cert that worked OK in Firefox before the CA certificate expired. Please note that webserver certificate is not involved in this problem.

Comment: @JW0914, this is a client certificate, used to authenticate the client to the webserver. Like being used in a browser, or using the `--cert` flag for `curl`. In this particular case, Firefox is not selecting the client certificate, while Chrome is.

Comment: @Richlv I did misunderstand then and will delete the applicable comments above to de-clutter. Did you delete the previously expired certificate from the certificate store and clear Firefox's cache _(this is the recommended procedure according to numerous sites if you google the error message: `Error code: SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT`)_

Comment: The expired certificate was not present in the certificate store - the CA certificate was the one that expired, the client certificate is still good. One Firefox instance had never accessed the target site before, so it had clean cache in that regard from the very beginning.

Comment: Hey, your client cert's validity period starts before the issuing CA's validity period starts. Maybe Firefox is choking on that.

Comment: @Spiff, an interesting observation. But that would prevent users from updating the CA certificate without making all issued client certificates invalid, right?

Comment: @JW0914, that would happen on the webserver side in this case. Webserver is aware of the CA certificate. We seem not to get to the verifying step, though. Firefox doesn't even send the client certificate,

Comment: @Richlv _(I had deleted this to add to it, but you replied when doing so, so I'll add a new comment)_ Right, but the CA has to be in the store in order to verify chain of trust, either by directly importing the CA into the Root CA store or by concatenating it into the client cert _(Windows: `cmd /c type .\CA.crt.pem .\client.crt.pem > .\Client-Chain.crt.pem` || All others: `cat ./CA.crt.pem ./client.crt.pem > ./Client-Chain.crt.pem`)_.

Comment: @Richlv If it's not what I mentioned before, the only other thing I can discern it to be from the error is a cipher error, where the site is not using what Firefox considers a secure cipher _(client cert lacks KU `keyAgreement`, which is required for certain ciphers; the three KUs `digitalSignature`, `keyEncipherment`, and `keyAgreement` affect what encryption protocols/ciphers can be used, which is why I always recommend specifying all three - example: [Line 877](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf))_. I'd troubleshoot with the site at this point

Comment: @JW0914, I wouldn't expect the designated key usage to affect ciphers. Not sure what you mean by "troubleshoot with the site" - I'm generating the CA cert and using the client cert, there's no other party involved in this test.

Comment: @Richlv I would encourage you to read OpenSSL's man pages then if you're not going to reference line 877 and higher in the prior link... As I stated, those three KUs are what affects what ciphers and protocols can be used... I only list RSA, DSA, and DH in the link, as all others are insecure for what I initially created that `openssl.cnf` for.

Comment: Heya @JW0914, appreciate the help - but it should not be a problem with key usage. If a new client certificate is generated, it works with the new CA certificate in Firefox.

Comment: @Spiff, to test the validity period possibility, regenerated the CA cert to have start time 10 years on the past - that did not help.

Comment: @Richlv Something doesn't add up, as the specific error being received is specific to only the few things mentioned in my prior comments. If you issue `openssl x509 -inform pem -in ca.crt.pem -noout -text` for both CAs, is all of the non-unique output the same? You may want to reach out to Mozilla directly or a Mozilla / OpenSSL specific forum due to the specific error you're receiving appearing to only have a handful of causes, all of which you've ruled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem was with the old cert using `PrintableStrings` for all strings, but the new one using `UTF8Strings` for some.
Regenerating the new one with `PrintableStrings` fixes it.

When OpenSSL tools are used, the [string_mask](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-req.html) option allows to control field encoding.

All credit for spotting the difference goes to Mozilla security engineer, Dana.

Comment: Do you have issue number in mozilla tracker ?

Comment: Sure, that would be https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1654596 .

Comment: Thanks. I have the same problem. How I can see how the CA is encoded? `PrintableStrings` or `UTF8Strings`. What command do you use?

Comment: I saw your comment in Mozilla issue and I have exactly the same problem.
The CA uses `PrintableStrings` and my certificate uses `UTF8Strings`. I have tried to create my certificate using `PrintableStrings` but it is always generated using `UTF8Strings` Do you know how to generate them using `PrintableStrings`?

Comment: That depends on the tools used, but for OpenSSL `string_mask` option allows to control this - also added in the answer.